# Python byte-string substring slices return different representations

Tags: python, arrays

In trying to prune a preceding and trailing bracket - [ and ] - I encountered something unexpected. In the python 3.7 interpreter:

```
>>> string = [b'0123456789']
>>> string[0][:5]
b'01234'
>>> string[0][0]
48
>>> string[0][:5] == b'01234'
True
>>> string[0][0] == b'0'
False
```

This feels to me like an inconsistency. I am new to Python, so, am I interpreting this correctly, is this odd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this isn't odd:

```
>>> type(b'0')
<class 'bytes'>
>>> type(b'0'[0])
<class 'int'>
```

So, an *element* of `bytes` is an integer. Obviously, an integer cannot equal a `bytes` object because it's meaningless (how do you compare `b'123'` and `12`, for example?).

Quote from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes):

> Since bytes objects are sequences of integers (akin to a tuple), for a bytes object `b`, `b[0]` will be an *integer*, while `b[0:1]` will be a bytes object of length 1.

Comment: Thanks, I interpreted [0] as being equal to [0:1]. Interesting.